# Calculating the change of entropy for non equilibrium states

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, non-equilibrium

In "Heat and Thermodynamics" by Dittman and Zemansky, section 8.10 (7th ed.) it's explained how to calculate the change in entropy in a system going from a non equilibrium state to an equilibrium state: a metal rod starting with a temperature gradient. The technique is to imagine that every infinitesimal element of the rod is undergoing a reversible process from its own initial temperature to the equilibrium temperature, calculate its change in entropy and the integrate for all elements in the rod.

Is this technique justifiable? can it be proven that one can model every element undergoing a reversible process and get a correct answer? Can you always use this approach and separate a system in infinitesimal elements undergoing reversible processes, regardless of the specifics of the problem?

Comment: What an excellent question!!!!  Many engineers and physicists subscribe to this viewpoint but some insist that the entropy can only be evaluated properly for a truly thermodynamic equilibrium state.  I my judgment, if it is not exact, it provides an excellent approximation for virtually all practical situations.

Comment: If the sum of all the components or subprocesses is reversible, the entire process must also be reversible. Clearly this is not true, but as @ChetMiller mentioned, it's probably a good approximation. However, I don't see how it's a good approximation if there is significant entropy generation associated with the approach to equilibrium. This method can't account for that.

Comment: @Drew With respect, I disagree.  For details of how this works, including how to calculate the local rate of entropy generation per unit volume in a system at a given time during an irreversible process, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 11, Problem 11.D.1.  If you are interested, I can also provide a specific example involving, say, transient heat conduction to a slab or rod.  See also my responses in the following thread:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/show-that-entropy-is-a-state-function.982870/page-2#post-6284976

Comment: @ChetMiller Super cool, thanks. On your PF post, it's interesting that the entropy generation comes out of the integration due to a differential balance, even though nowhere in the differential balance we made any statements about irreversibility. This clashes with my current understanding that a process is reversible if all of its components are reversible, but maybe I'm thinking about this wrong.

Comment: @drew The entropy generation arises from finite rates of transport processes, heat conduction and viscous momentum transfer (dissipation).